# How to set a Printer Port in C# on a specified Printer

Tags: c#, com, ports, printers

I want to be able to do the equivalent of the following in c#:

- Go into "Devices and Printers"
- Right click a printer
- Go to the ports tab
- Select COM12: port
- click OK

I have managed to get a ManagementObject for a named printer and tried to call:

> mObj.SetPropertyValue("PortName","COM12:");

On the ManagementObject for that Printer - whch inherits from ManagementBaseObject.

However, this piece of code didn't do anything to the Printer Settings.

I suspect that I will need to use P/Invoke on the appropriate library but after a lot of searching I cannot find the library or a tutorial for how to do this from c#.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer on an obscure part of the internet:

```
public static void SetPrinterPort(string printerName, string portName)
        {
            var oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
            oManagementScope.Connect();

            SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
            oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer 
            WHERE Name = '" + printerName.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "'";

            ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher =
               new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, @oSelectQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject oItem in oObjectCollection)
            {
                oItem.Properties["PortName"].Value = portName;
                oItem.Put();
            }
        }
```

I am pretty sure that the last part is all you need to set properties on any Management Object.  It was driving me nuts that I could see that the Win32 API said the property I wanted to set was read/write but nowhere seemed to have the code for setting it.

Well now we know! :-)

I hope this is useful for someone.